# WPF Navigation - Random Access - Go to directed page not just forward or back

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using WPF Page navigation in a c# windows based application. There are a series of pages that I am creating like this

```
Page TargetPage =  new myPage01();
TargetFrame.Navigate(TargetPage);
```

The first-time page creation and navigation are working fine, and because I am passing by object the pages are kept alive for me to reference at a later point.

When the user hits the last page (all different views of the same data) and clicks the next button I want the UI to "loop" around to the first page. I am trying to figure out how I can redirect the frame to that first page. I do not want to rely on the built-in journal history within the GUI itself. How can I reference the first page previously created or for that matter any of the previously created pages by referring to it in the code. All the page navigation examples I have come accross are always creating the page as new or using the back or next to navigate to other pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to rely on the built-in journal history within the GUI itself.

If you do not want to do that you need to keep track of everything yourself, which i would not recommend unless there is something wrong with the build-in functionality. You can probably find the first page to be the last item of the [`BackStack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.backstack.aspx).

Comment: Just to clarify when I say I don't want to use the journal, I just don't want the user to have to rely on the GUI. If I can use the journal programatically to access specific pages then that would be fantastic... if there is a way I don't know how... thanks.